# How to secure ColdFusion cookies with HTTPOnly/ Secure attribute?

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, session-cookies, coldfusion-11

I am trying to help a company who is experiencing an issue with their ColdFusion website. The issue is a PCI scan failure due to "insecure cookies with HTTPOnly/ Secure Flag attributes".

Previously I fixed this error for 3 other cookies: JSESSIONID, CFID, CFTOKEN by editing the web.xml file; however, this time the issue is apparently with a session cookie created inside of the Application.cfm.

To be specific:

```
<cfapplication name="testname" sessionmanagement="Yes" 
loginStorage="session" CLIENTMANAGEMENT="YES" 
SESSIONTIMEOUT=#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0)#>
```

So far I have tried following the CFApplication.html from Adobe (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-a-b/cfapplication.html) to fix this, but have not had any luck. Any assistance or guidance is appreciated in fixing this matter. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Usually you don't need to edit the web.xml files. You can set cookie handling in your application.cfm/cfc using the setClientCookies variable or (re)setting the cookies using the cfcookie tag in your applications logic.

Comment: Yes, but this customer has multiple sites all hosted utilizing Coldfusion all with insecure cookies and that was the quickest route I found to fix them all at once. Looking into it there seemed to be an issue with Tomcat and CF11 with those cookies. This is the source I used for that fix: https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/how-to-set-up-httponly-and-secure-flag-for-session-cookies/td-p/6448928/page/2

Comment: Can you show the code that is setting that session cookie?  What you have provided so far with the cfapplication tag is setting those 3 cookies you have already fixed.

Comment: Yes, I tried to edit the original post; however, it would not let me. The current code is ''' <cfapplication name="Test" sessionmanagement="Yes" loginStorage="session" CLIENTMANAGEMENT="YES"  SESSIONTIMEOUT=#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0)#> ''' This is all that exists within the current applications.cfm file.

Comment: That's the same as what you have already provided.  What is the name of the cookie you need to secure?

Comment: That is my issue, the PCI scan is declaring that the CFapplication "Test" is insecure and not set as HTTPOnly/ Secure.

Comment: You are talking about 2 different things.  "Test" (or whatever the actual value is) is the name of your ColdFusion application.  That is NOT a cookie.  The PCI scan should tell you the cookie's name.  What is that name?  It may be the same as your application name but that application name is not exposed to anything the PCI scan can see. You have already secured the cookies that ColdFusion uses to maintain session (the 3 you mention). So the code is likely setting a cookie(s) somewhere else. Search the codebase for "cookie" and see what it brings back.

Comment: Alternatively you may have the ability to add the cookie attributes with a fronted web server, if you are using one. This blog post with the Lucee cfml engine might be helpful https://dev.lucee.org/t/pci-compliance-non-secure-session-cookies-identified/8452

Comment: Miguel-F, The Cookies the PCI scan highlights are JSESSION, CFID, and CFTOKEN. After following aforementioned ways of fixing them and reporting them back as secure HTTPOnly flag, I tried to dispute the issue with the PCI manager. They then denied the dispute claiming "Can your organization confirm that "test" is not responsible for starting or maintaining an authenticated session?" The actual variable for test is only referenced in the codebase as the name for the CFApplication name. I apologize if I am incorrect in thinking or missing information, As I said below I am pretty new to CF.

Comment: Okay I was confused. I thought you said you had those 3 cookies secured already. Read this article and try what it says there for the ColdFusion version you are running - [Setting up HTTPOnly Session Cookies for ColdFusion](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/764.cfm)

Comment: I do have those 3 cookies secure already, that is why I am confused and looking for help for this. I can open Google Chrome and see that those three cookies all are set for: Send for "Secure same-site connections only" and Accessible to script No (HttpOnly). The PCI manager responded with the question of "Can your organization confirm that "test" is not responsible for starting or maintaining an authenticated session?" instead of verifying those three cookies as secure. Am I wrong in thinking that the CFApplication session doesn't/ can't be secured in this way?

Comment: AFAIK for cookies, they just need to be set as "secure" and "httponly". If your PCI vendor is failing your site they should explain to you exactly why. That's the whole point in having them run the scan. Are users logging into this ColdFusion application?  I assume yes so you cannot accept that question. What exactly are they telling you is the failing part on the cookies? You have stated that these flags are already set on all 3 of those cookies. Our PCI vendor always wants to fail us on the CFID and CFTOKEN cookies as they can be guessed. But when you use JSESSIONID those cookies aren't used

Comment: More info on that here - [Predictable Cookie Session ID''s Reported by Compliance Tests](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/predictable-cookie-session-ids-reported.html) Unfortunately even though you switch to JSESSIONID cookie the other 2 cookies are still sent to the client. There is no way I know of to stop that behavior. Unless you use some other appliance to remove those cookies before sending back to the client

Comment: "Description
A Cookie Vulnerability helps an attacker to gain access to session information stored in cookies. It may also be used as a 'locator' attack that precedes a Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) or Man-In-The-Middle attack. When looking for Cookie Vulnerabilities, an attacker will first observe cookies through various HTTP proxies and check their attributes. The attacker will then try to steal cookies of various users by employing multiple attacks. If successful, he/she may be able to get sensitive information which can be further used in an illegitimate way." Is the exact error they give.

Comment: LOL!  but that doesn't explain why they are flagging your application.  That is just generic info on the vulnerability of cookies. They should be able to tell you "we are flagging cookie abc because of xyz".

Comment: As for their evidence they say: " Cookie does not have secure attribue in HTTPS Cookie does not have an HTTPOnly Attribute" and linking the path to the website's path with "Cookie Vulnerabilities Found Test" Where test is the CFApplication name. Then it says Request: Post followed by those three cookies. I fixed this same issue before on another site for this company by simply securing those three cookies.

Comment: Did they re-scan after you made these changes?  It doesn't make sense if you have verified with browser dev tools that those settings are indeed enabled on the cookies.

Comment: Ok so I'm not insane? lol Again I am a very new web developer and am learning as I go but thought they should be explain this more thoroughly since it is a failed PCI scan. I have called twice and disputed to get more information 4 times now to arrive with the information I have provided.

Comment: No, you are not crazy.  Keep on them.  They need to provide you that information so you can fix the vulnerability.  I've had similar frustrations with these companies before. You usually need to get to the 2nd or 3rd level support to get actual details.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad I am not insane on this cause it has been wrecking my nerves! I did perform a scan after making changes and testing last week but it still returned false, I will perform a scan now and dispute again if it fails. This usually takes 4 hours or so, so I will comeback with more information then. Thank you so much for the assistance!

Comment: No worries.  Good luck.  If it does fail again, the only other thing I can think of is to check if the request is different when they request it versus when you request it. Are you accessing the site in the same way they are? Paths are different when coming from the internet versus you being on the network. Maybe something in between is mucking with the cookies?  Try accessing your site with browser dev tools from the internet and verify the cookie settings. Maybe you have already done this.

Comment: Yes I have already done this and verified via dev tools. Originally (Last Tuesday) these cookies were all set without the HTTPOnly and Secure flags, but after working on them (last Wednesday) I was able to verify with Dev Tools as well as creating new cookies in browsers that they were now showing as secure and HTTPOnly.

Comment: They should at least be able to tell you the cookie name, lol!

Comment: Hey all sorry got really busy over the weekend! They solved it Miguel they were disputing the Application.cfm session as a cookie and telling me to secure that. I don't exactly know why they flagged that, but it seems to be "fixed" for now so thank you!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. If you can describe the solution go ahead and answer your own question here. It is okay to do that. It might help someone else if they run across a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to the ColdFusion administrator for these sites?  In the Server Settings-->Memory Variable section are universal settings for the session cookies: HTTPOnly and Secure Only.  Make sure those are turned on.

In addition, do the sites use the CFCOOKIE tag.  Make sure those tags are setting the 'secure' and 'httponly' attributes to TRUE.

Last, are the sites declaring COOKIE scoped vars in any CFPARAM tags/calls?  If so, those will set cookies and are *not* secure and there is no setting I've found to make them so.

Comment: Yes to the first two points. My initial reaction was to secure through the CF admin; however, this did not work and I found the alternative way to secure through following https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/how-to-set-up-httponly-and-secure-flag-for-session-cookies/td-p/6448928/page/2. CFCookie is declared here and there through the sites; however, I have seemingly fixed this where I can. The problem the PCI scan is having now is that it says the CFApplication session is insecure/ not set as HTTPOnly. The code I provided above is the creation of the session.

Comment: As for the last point you make, I am wondering if this could be the issue, this site (along with the others) were created back in 2014 - 2016 and the creator has since passed away. I am new to CF and only have a few years experience in web development as is so this has been a task and a half for me to figure out. I have fixed about 30 cookies for this company but this last one has me boggled!

Comment: The only code the PCI scan has given me to go off of is the session name I provided above in the CFApplication code. I have changed the name to keep anonymity for the site, but that session's actual name is unique and only found once throughout the site, in the CFApplication.cfm